# How to disable PASTE in Excel without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

This is an old question - 
You can't really force validation rules in excel b/c even if you protect your sheet a simple copy/paste can bypass all validation (very strange implementation of protection from Microsoft and a poor one IMHO)

Now - There are many solution how to catch paste using VBA or even cancel it and force validation, but they worth nothing, as the user can disable vba code before opening the workbook and again we have no protection.

Is there a way to really protect the validation on cells (even by removing paste completely) WITHOUT USING VBA Code ?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it may be interesting: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53a4a766-cb3d-4150-b1f4-0e7d6e05bafa/add-restrictions-to-copycutpaste-in-excel-when-a-worksheet-is-protected